# ssh-connecting to rbash won't source the .profile file

Tags: bash, ssh, libssh

I am using [libssh](http://www.libssh.org/) to connect to a remote machine and execute commands.

The connection works fine, but here's the rub: on the distant machine, the bash that is running while I'm connected is a rbash. When I send `ps | grep ungreppable_phrase` to be executed on the other machine, here is the output:

```
root 25989 25987 0 07:47 ? 00:00:00 rbash -c ps -ef | grep ungreppable_phrase
```

(I removed the grep command from that list)

So, obviously, `rbash` is the remote shell.

Now, [rbash man page](http://man.he.net/man1/rbash) tells us the startup files are read before any of the rbash restrictions are applied. So, if any of my startup files (/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile; ~/.bash_user or ~/.profile) contains a definition for `PATH`, that definition should be visible when I run my commands. Especially, if there are some executable files in one of the directories of `PATH`, I should be able to run it.

Here's a line from my .profile file:

```
PATH=/home/my_user/bin
```

Somehow, I managed to run a `ls` in there. It does contain executable files.

My ~/.profile is the [last file](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) to be sourced, and it doesn't contain any sourcing of another file. Nor any redefinition of `PATH`.

But I get a "command not found" error (or something that looks like it very much, the echo $? returns 127).

Can someone tell me why it seems that my .profile file isn't sourced when I remotely log in?
Is it due to some code in libssh ? I'm trying to explore it to find if there are some special otpions that are passed to rbash that I can't see with the grep above..

(Since we're in rbash mode, I can't simply require the PATH to be changed)

Many thanks,
Pascal

Comment: Tagged "bash" as I can't tag it "rbash" yet ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I finally found what was wrong.

After some investigation, it appeared that when I logged into the machine via `ssh {username}@{host}` (via the libssh API), `whoami` wouldn't reply `username`, but, instead, replied `root`(yes, root. 0:0, allmight, and everything. THE super-user).

I checked the /etc/passwd file, and, at my biggest surprise, username also had 0:0 userid.

root sources bash (whereas {username} would use rbash) in my environment. Hence the problem found above.

Now, why ssh switches to "name1" when "name1" and "name2" are aliases, and you run `ssh name2@host` via libssh still remains obscure. But at least, I know why my connection above wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The man page you linked indicates that this is regular bash, then it gets restricted. So, how is your bash [getting started](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)? How bash starts tells it what files to read. Note also that when it searches for `~/.profile` it will only use it if you don't also have a `~/.bash_profile` file. It only looks for these files if bash is run as an interactive login shell.

Farther down the page, you can see where it reads `~/.bashrc` for shells started by ssh. In summary, the most likely explanation is that none of the files you mention are actually being read, if you have no `~/.bashrc` file or it does not source your `~/.profile`.

Comment: I found this in libssh's code: ssh_channel_request_exec , which is what I use to run the command, has the following comment: /** * @brief Run a shell command without an interactive shell. * * This is similar to 'sh -c command'. */ This makes me think that's how the shell is invoked